# What do brackets mean in the output of pstree?

Tags: process

What are the differences between  `[]` and `{}` and `[{}]` used to enclose a process in the output of pstree? I guess `[]` is used for specifying more than one processes. For example,

```
init-+-NetworkManager-+-dhclient
     |                |-dnsmasq
     |                `-2*[{NetworkManager}]
     |-accounts-daemon---{accounts-daemon}
     |-acpid

...

     |-gnome-terminal-+-7*[bash---emacs]
     |                |-6*[bash]
     |                |-2*[bash---less]
     |                |-bash-+-2*[grep]
     |                |      |-less
     |                |      `-locate
     |                |-bash-+-less
     |                |      `-pstree
     |                |-bash-+-emacs
     |                |      `-okular---2*[{okular}]
     |                |-gnome-pty-helpe
     |                `-3*[{gnome-terminal}]
```

I only have one `okular` process run from a shell process with `nohup` and `&`.  Why do I have `okular---2*[{okular}]`?

I don't understand the manpage about

> Child threads of a process are found under the parent process and are shown with the process name in curly braces, e.g.

```
   icecast2---13*[{icecast2}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man pstree`:

```
pstree  visually  merges  identical  branches by putting them in square
brackets and prefixing them with the repetition count, e.g.

       init-+-getty
            |-getty
            |-getty
            `-getty

becomes

       init---4*[getty]

Child threads of a process are found under the parent process  and  are
shown with the process name in curly braces, e.g.

       icecast2---13*[{icecast2}]
```

- `[]` denote identical  branches.
- `{}` denote child thread.

So `n[{process_name}]` meaning you have n threads under parent process `process_name`.

Comment: thanks. why some single-copy child processes are not in {}, such as `dhclient`? What does [{}] mean?

Comment: I only have one `okular` process run from a shell process with `nohup` and `&`.  Why do I have `okular---2*[{okular}]`?

Comment: Because it has two child thread. In your input, there an exmaple of one parent - one child thread `accounts-daemon---{accounts-daemon}`.

Comment: Threads in Linux are implemented as child processes. In the past they actually had different PIDs but that has since been fixed. So it's just showing threads.